# Unable to pass certain IR remote key codes to Android

Tags: android, linux, drivers

I'm trying to use an IR remote to pass certain key codes to Android.  So far, I'm able to pass numeric keys (0-9) and D-pad keys (up, down, left, right, enter).  Now I'm trying to extend the keys to include other characters like a-z.

The code that I'm modifying is an IR driver in the Linux kernel part of Android.  It's similar to [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/misc/winbond-cir.c?v=2.6.36) driver.  However, when I pass a value like KEY_A (maps "a" to 30: defined in Linux's include/linux/[input.h](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/input.h?v=2.6.11.8)), Android doesn't see it.

The section of code that passes the command up is the following:

```
        input_report_key(cir->input, cir->last_key, 1);
        input_report_key(cir->input, cir->last_key, 0);
        input_sync(cir->input);
```

When I print cir->last_key, I can see the value 30 when I press the "a" button.  However, I'm not sure how to trace the code from here to Android to see where the button press is being dropped.

In Android, I have a file called /system/usr/keylayout/qwerty.kl that maps values, e.g. 30 maps to "a".  The problem is Android never gets the value of 30 when I press "a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keybit field of [this](http://ww2.cs.fsu.edu/~rosentha/linux/2.6.26.5/docs/DocBook/kernel-api/re1158.html) structure has to be set to include all the key codes being passed.

For example,

```
set_bit(KEY_A, input_dev->keybit);
```